# How do I end a program if a char the user entered a "." or a "-"?

Tags: java

We're updating our previous lab and one of the requirements is that if a user enters a '.' or '-' we have to output a message that they should run the program again and the program exits.

This is what I have so far. I'm not sure if I have to use loops for this program.

```
System.out.print("\t Enter Employee Number: ");
employeeNumber = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
      if (employeeNumber == '.' && employeeNumber == '-'){
          System.out.println("\t Invalid Employee Number.");
          System.out.println("\t Please run the program again.");
          System.out.println("Thank you for using \"TEMPLE HUMAN RESOURCES\"");
          System.exit(0);
```

Also, the variable employeeNumber is a char.

Comment: What type is the `keyboard`?

Comment: Whether it should loop depends on your requirements.  We can't answer that.

Comment: You should probably use `||` instead of `&&`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 3, within the if statement, there should be a Conditional-OR operator. This compares if either condition adjacent is true or false. If either one is true, the whole condition is set to a value of true.

```
if (employeeNumber == '.' || employeeNumber == '-'){
```

You may want to do this instead, because this looks through every single character of the string and tells if it is true or false through the boolean.

```
String employeeNumber = keyboard.next();
Boolean works = true;
for(int a = 0; a < employeeNumber.length(); a++) {
    if (employeeNumber.charAt(a) == '.' || employeeNumber.charAt(a) == '-'){
        works = false;
    }
}
if(!works) {
    System.out.println("\t Invalid Employee Number.");
    System.out.println("\t Please run the program again.");
    System.out.println("Thank you for using \"TEMPLE HUMAN RESOURCES\"");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Conditional-AND operators are represented as "&&" and set the condition to true, only if all joined expressions result to true.

Comment: It only works if the '.' is in the beginning. What if the user enters 35.7? That's what I'm trying to figure out now. Since the charAt(0) is set to 0, it only takes the character at the index 0.

Comment: Simply create a for loop to iterate through each character until it reaches the end of the string. Upon each iteration check the chars against '-' or '.' and if they appear, set to false.

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I will type out the code.

Comment: My for loop is not working. It exits the program without evaluating the rest of the condition.

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Error? This isn't supposed to print anything.

Comment: When I enter a number, for example 36.547. It just exits the program.

Comment: `if (employeeNumber.indexOf('.') >= 0 ...`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your using && instead of ||.

Answer (score 0):

`employeeNumber == '.' && employeeNumber == '-'` will always return false, for two reasons.

1.) You need to use `.equals()` instead of the `==` operator because `==` is an operator for the specific location of the object in the JVM, and will only return true if the objects being compared are the same exact objects. `equals()` is used only for the value of the variable. So, `employeeNumber == '.'` is always false, but `employeeNumber.equals('.')` could be true.

2.) `employeeNumber.equals('.') && employeeNumber.equals('-')` will still always be false, because you are using the logical and operator (&&) and a `String` cannot equal 2 values at once. Instead, you need to use the logical or operator (||). Your code should look like this:

```
if (employeeNumber.equals('.') || employeeNumber.equals('-')) {
    // Exit the program
```